# Дублировать данные MySQL из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: mysql

Подскажите мысли, нужно чтобы данные таблицы tabl1.stolbec1 дублировались и сохранялись в таблице tabl2.stolbec3
Подскажите как можно реализовать

tabl1=таблица1
stolbec1=столбец1 в таблице1

tabl2=таблица3
stolbec3=столбец3 в таблице2

Comment: связь то между этими таблицами какая-то есть?

Comment: В одной базе данных... Или это не возможно?

Comment: Покажите пример данных - обе таблицы исходно (по 3-5 записей) и конечный результат для именно этих данных.

Answer (score 0):

Формально

```sql
UPDATE tabl1
JOIN tabl2 USING (id)
SET tabl2.stolbec3 = tabl1.stolbec1;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду пробовать

Comment: Получилось, но продублировалась первая запись из tabl1.stolbec1 во всю таблицу tabl2.stolbec3..надо поле в поле (разные записи в полях) ...Голову сломал уже)

Comment: @Виктор *продублировалась первая запись из tabl1.stolbec1 во всю таблицу tabl2.stolbec3* Значит, неправильно связал таблицы. Должен быть критерий типа "Поле Х из первой таблицы равно полю Y из второй таблицы", причём он должен любой записи из второй таблицы сопоставлять строго одну запись из первой таблицы.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!